# Including initial value in a select Statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a select query which returns the following o/p..
1 Arun,
2 Kumar,
3 Babu,
4 Ram,

Is it possible to add a intial value to this o/p without inserting a value to the table, in other means hardcoding the intial value.
Can i get the o/p as

0 Select,
1 Arun,
2 Kumar,
3 Babu,
4 Ram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    0, 
   'Select'
union all
<your query>
```